# Liouville's theorem on the tangent bundle

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

One interpretation of Liouville's theorem is the determinism and reversibility of classical mechanics, i.e. the mechanical states can't converge or diverge. The theorem is often formulated on the phase space, which is the cotangent bundle of the configuration space. However, since points on the tangent bundle of the configuration space (where the Lagrangian is defined) also define a mechanical state, I wonder whether Liouville's theorem can be cast to Lagrangian mechanics as well? If not possible, then why is that?

Comment: Duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/358322/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to obtain an analogous of Liouville's Theorem in terms of the Configuration Space?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/358322/)

Comment: @GiorgioP This doesn't answer the question directly. I still don't know why the determinism on the tangent bundle doesn't give a similar theorem like Liouville's theorem? Surely the count of states will remain the same along the flow. Is it purely due to the lack of canonical two form, hence no way to measure the volume of the states?